# Python .pyw extension does not work

Tags: python, cmd, python-3.4

I'm trying to run a program without cmd window pop-up when I double click it or when I make it exe. So I wanted to save it as .pyw extension but when I double click to script, shell can't run it. It says I need to select the program to run it or search online. How can I fix this? Windows- Python 3.4

It was okay in 3.5 when I use .pyw extension. First time I see this problem.

Comment: Sounds like you need to associate the correct program with the .pyw extension in Windows.

Comment: @WyattIsrael Correct program is Python shell? I tried that, nothing happend. Normally when I save a script, the icon on the script is Python icon. But for this it's nothing, a blank page.

Comment: .pyw should be associated with pythonw.exe I believe. Did you try that?

Comment: If it worked okay in Python 3.5, why did you downgrade to Python 3.4?

Comment: Type `ftype /?` and `assoc /?`. This is a system config problem not a programming problem.

Comment: @cricket_007 Because most of modules I using does not work on 3.5 so I back to 3.4.

Comment: rightclick .pyw choose open with -> check use this program aleays and choose python.exe from 3.4 installation

Answer (score 0):

I always have this problem whenever I reinstall Python.

Very simple fix (at least on Windows):

1) Create a .pyw file

2) Right-click on it and select properties

3) In "Opens with:" press change

4) Navigate to your python directory and choose "pythonw.exe"